# Work with SequentialWorkflowActivity in WF4

Tags: .net, migration, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow application developped with WF 3.5 and I'm migrating to 4.5.
My application is using a class which is inheriting from SequentialWorkflowActivity and this class is not existing in the 4.5 version.

how can I solve this problem?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the class is now [System.Activities.Statements.Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.activities.statements.sequence.aspx) which is sealed.

What problem is it, what you intend to solve using inheritance? Could you not use composition of several activities to solve your task?

Comment: the class you mentioned replaces the System.workflow.activities.SequenceActivity class. SequentialWorkflowActivities inherits from that one. And as you saw it , the new sequence class is sealed.

 I'm using this class to define dependencyProperties and methods to the workflow this is not for completing a task

Comment: could you be more specific about your dependencyProperties and methods? maybe some code?

Comment: I can't show the code i'm in an internship and the code is confidential. Finally I derived from NativeActivity but now I don't know how to deal with the old SequentialActivityDesigner that wen can see on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.workflow.componentmodel.design.sequentialactivitydesigner%28v=vs.85%29.aspx